# Where to put arcgis map after installing the app on devices

Tags: android, arcgis, android-install-apk

I have create an app , it is location based app. The map is created by us and we want to protect it , so I want to put the map somewhere that no one can get it , I thought about the

`assets` folder , but I can not get the file read from there, 
I can read the map file like this

```
ArcGISLocalTiledLayer localTiledLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("the map.tk");
```

which this way does not work for assets folder even with absolute path.

So is there any other options? or even assets folder (which is read only)?
because I couldn't get anything anywhere

Comment: if the app can get at it, likely so can a user... it is their device, after all.

Comment: but if it is inside the apk file the user can not get it, it only can use it

Comment: an apk is just a zip file.

Comment: so @MarcB you mean i can open any other .apk apps i want? and get whatever files i want?

Comment: If you can get the apk file, you can unzip and rummage around at your leasure. It's just like a java .jar file - it's also just a .zip